# Replacing "&" with "&amp;" with clojure.string/replace

Tags: regex, clojure

Pretty self-explanatory. I have a string that contains the ampersand character, and I need to replace it with the character reference.

I've tried a variety of regex patterns to try and replace it, but none of them work (these are just a few):

```
(s/replace string #"\Q&\E" "&amp;")
(s/replace string #"\\Q&\\E" "&amp;")
(s/replace string #"\\&" "&amp;")
(s/replace string #"&" "&amp;")
```

Comment: These two worked for me

`(clojure.string/replace "bean & cheese" #"\Q&\E" "&amp;")`
`(clojure.string/replace "bean & cheese" #"&" "&amp;")`

Comment: the non-regex version worked as well
`(clojure.string/replace "bean & cheese" "&" "&amp;")`

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to user the string/string form of replace (instead of a regex):

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:require
    [clojure.string :as str]
    [ring.util.codec :as codec] ))

(def data "hello & goodbye")

(str/replace data "&" "&amp") => "hello &amp goodbye"
```

You may also be interested in Ring Codec  `[ring/ring-codec "1.1.0"]`

```
(codec/url-encode     data) => "hello%20%26%20goodbye"
(codec/percent-encode data) => "%68%65%6C%6C%6F%20%26%20%67%6F%6F%64%62%79%65"
(codec/form-encode    data) => "hello+%26+goodbye"
```

Comment: I tried that one too, and it didn't work for me... `(s/replace string "&" "&amp;")`

Should note that it works fine on the REPL, but not within defn for some reason. EDIT: Nevermind, bad syntax on my part. This actually works fine! Thanks!